# .htaccess files not working on apache

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf reads:

```
<Directory>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I have mod_rewrite enabled

Under /var/www/sitename
I have my .htaccess file which reads:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Yet, when access localhost/sitename/directory I get a 404 error

What am I missing here?

Comment: Turn on lots of debugging, then check the logs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this an unsure how to turn on debugging / check logs.

Comment: tail -f /var/log/apache2/*.log

Then refresh your browser. Logging should be on by default.

Comment: I would have expected the directive < Directory>  to be < Directory /var/www> or < Directory /var/www/sitename>

Comment: I enabled logs, and when I refresh I just get an access log telling me that I'm getting a 404 error because the directory is not found. It seems that apache isn't taking my .htaccess file within the sitename directory into consideration.

Comment: I changed it to be <Direcory /var/www

Comment: After your change, did you reload the apache server? Did it make a difference to the 404 issue? You can reload the apache server with /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

Comment: It didn't help, but I want to be able to have multiple directories under /var/www each having their own .htaccess files So for now I'm going to change it back to /var/www

Comment: I have found a reference to something required for Ubuntu, which could be the OS you are using. Try a2enmod rewrite && /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: These are in my error logs [Sat Nov 30 17:24:03.698771 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13273] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 30 17:24:04.799729 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13375] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 30 17:24:04.799787 2013] [core:notice] [pid 13375] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `RewriteRule ^(directory)($|/) - [L]` above the first `RewriteCond` so it will exclude the directory from `RewriteRule` you can add more than 1 directory by seperating them with `|` like `RewriteRule ^(forum|extras)($|/) - [L]`

Here is an example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(directory)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Comment: Can you use pastebin.com and put the entire apache configuration file?

Comment: I think I see my problem

Comment: Yes your AllowOveride is set to None. :)

Comment: The apache configuration is setup correctly, in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` there should be a file named `000-default.conf`. Please post that on pastebin.com

Answer (score 0):

For people using ubuntu I found this answer to be complete.

https://askubuntu.com/a/48363

Comment: For some reasons apache isn't reading my default.conf files so I had to change the settings under /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule process-id-(.*)\.htm$ process.php?id=$1
```